# Exim Filter to change recipient

Tags: exim

Lets say I have this filter for user1 who doesn't exist on our network, but has an external email we want to send the emails to:

```
if
 $header_to: matches "user1@domain.com"
then
 deliver "user1@externaldomain.com"
endif
```

If someone then sends a mail to `user1@domain.com` it correctly gets delivered to `user1@externaldomain.com`

However, if they send to `user1@domain.com, user2@domain.com` then the email *only* gets delivered to `user1@externaldomain.com`

`user2@domain.com` doesn't get sent the email.

I think this is because the `deliver` command is significant, so nothing further happens.

Normally, you would use `unseen deliver` to ensure the email is processed further - but then this would (I assume) result in the email being delivered to `user1@domain.com` locally (in addition to user2@domain.com), which isn't wanted.

What is the right way to set up this filter so that the emails will go to the external party and the internal user if they are both in the To: field?

Comment: A dirty workaround for a limited number of cases: what do you about to create a user1 on the system with `/bin/nologin` as no-login shell, one dedicated group and a .alias with the external address in his home directory?

Comment: [This Article](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/exim/users/86572) could be another option.

Comment: @Hastur Yes, I thought of using an alias etc, but I want to use these from time to time, and the set up and tear down will be frustrating.  I figure I must be missing something.  Like a `unseen  deliver` then a discard later for the local.

Comment: It has to be a straightforward and orthodox way; I agree just I don't know it. As said in advance...  __dirty__ and for a __limited number of cases__. If it is only one you can always change the `.forward` in `"|cat > /dev/null"`, quotes mandatory. Hint remembered [here](https://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2008/08/06/forward-and-devnull/). You can even set a special group `mailghosts` and restrict access with ssh... ps> When you find the proper solution _double-check_  if it will work with user1 in the CC or BCC fields too...